# How to make `return` return a var and text

Tags: c++, return

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Event{
    public:
        Event(int x, int y, string z){
            setEvent(x, y, z);
        }//Constructor

        void setEvent(int a, int b, string c){
            if(a >= 0){
                if(a < b){
                    if(b <= 24){
                        start_time = a;
                        end_time = b;
                        event_name = c;
                    }
                    else cout <<"The end time for the event needs to be <=24 hours";
                }
                else cout <<"The start time for the event needs to be smaller than the end time";
            }
            else cout <<"The start time for the event needs to be >=0 hours";
        }//Code to set an event and check if the event is valid within the precondition

        void rename(string r){//Code to rename event
            event_name = r;
        }

        string duration(){
            int time_length = end_time - start_time;
            if(time_length == 1) return "1 hour";//I am stuck over here!!!
            else return time_length "hour";
        }

    private:
        int start_time;
        int end_time;
        string event_name;
};
```

If you look `void duration()` in the public class, I am trying to make `return` return text in one part and a var and text in another part. But I am unable to make it work.

```
     main.cpp:30:16: error: could not convert 'time_length' from 'int' to 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
else return time_length "hour";
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

main.cpp:30:28: error: expected ';' before string constant
    else return time_length "hour";
                            ^~~~~~

Is there a way to make `return` work or any alternative to fix this problem/code.

Comment: 1st of all you can't return anything from a **`void`** function. 2nd return something like a `std::pair<int, std::string>` for example.

Comment: Instead of giving it a downvote, please give feedback as well

Comment: @user0042 can you explain the 2nd you meant, it is unclear to what you mean.

Comment: @user0042 i know that is wrong to ask stuff, but why doesn't `return` text?

Comment: You might be looking for `return std::to_string(time_length) + " hour";`

Comment: @Praetorian can you explain where you got `to_string`?

Comment: When you call the function how will you tell it which type of return you want if it can return several different things?

Comment: @Galik I see. Thank you.

Comment: [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is part of the standard library, found in the `<string>` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `void` means the function will return nothing, so you cannot actually retreive any variables from this function.

A fix would be to give the function type `std::string`, EG

```
string duration(){
    int time_length = end_time - start_time;
    if(time_length == 1) return "1 hour";//I am stuck over here!!!
    else //Formulate a string otherwise
}
```

Note you are going to have to look into [building a string with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288970/c-how-to-build-strings-char), and put that logic into your else statement.

If you wish to return a pair, you are going to have to write another function with return type `std::pair<int, std::string>`